# How was this formula of voltage on capacitor achieved?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, formula-derivation

We know that voltage across a capacitor is given by

[image]

But there is this other formula

[image]

How this second formula was deducted mathematically from the first one? or from another one?

Comment: in the second formula, what is R, \$V_s\$ and \$V_c\$? You need to explain it to us

Comment: @FrancoVS - Vc should be voltage on capacitor. Vs will be the source voltage.

Comment: Do you know how to solve an ODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let I_r be current in the resistor = Vc/R at any time.

- Vc = Q/C from the basic definition of capacitance.
- dQ/dt = -I_r = -Vc/R From the basic definition of current.
- dQ/dt = -Q/CR

Apply initial conditions, Q at time 0 = Vs * C and do trivial calculus, then substitution to get Vc in place of Q.